# Get the tempos of a parsed MusicXML file

Tags: xml, musicxml

In MusicXML, there can be `direction` tags that have `<sound>` tags, which sets the BPM. For example,

```
      <direction placement="above">
        <direction-type>
          <words>Molto vivace</words>
          </direction-type>
        <staff>1</staff>
        <sound tempo="260"/>
        </direction>
```

Is it possible to get the tempo markings located by their offset in a Measure?

Edit: I used a piece downloaded from MuseScore. I have currently found a solution that requires preprocessing the XML file before parsing it. The XML file I used had `<direction>` elements that had the `<sound>` element but did not have a `<metronome>` element. So what I did was after every `<direction>` element that had a `<sound>` element, I added a new `<direction>` element that has a `<metronome>` element, this seems to be the only way music21 will actually parse the `<sound>` element, where it is then usable with `Stream.metronomeMarkBoundaries`. Example:

```
      <direction placement="above">
        <direction-type>
          <metronome parentheses="no" default-y="40.00" relative-x="-39.33" relative-y="3.81">
            <beat-unit>half</beat-unit>
            <per-minute>128</per-minute>
            </metronome>
          </direction-type>
        <staff>1</staff>
        <sound tempo="256"/>
      </direction>
```